# FMX ListView with LiveBindings

Tags: android, listview, delphi, livebindings

I am developing an FMX (Android) app using a `ListView` in Delphi 10.2.3. I have the `Listview` live(bound) to a `ClientDataSet` with `(Synch->*)`. This works very well, and any changes in `Listview` are propagated to the `ClientDataSet`, including the `ClientDataSet's` event handlers, such as `BeforeUpdate`, `Post` and `AfterScroll`.

Now when I move the record pointer in the ClientDataSet **programmatically**, the `Listview` **does not synch** with the change. It seems the `Livebinding` only works "one way" (from the UI to the Dataset).

How can I make the `Listview` follow the `ClientDataSet`, the way it does in the VCL when using a DataSource?

```
// here I expect the see the selected item start at the first item 
// in the UI in index order and move quickly down through the 
// list until it stops at the last one. This doesn't happen. The UI remains
// unaffected.
ClientModule.CDSData.First;
while not ClientModule.CDSData.Eof do
begin
   ClientModule.CDSData.Next;
   Sleep(100);
end;
```

Comment: From what I remember it is bidirectional in that if the data set changes that change is reflected in the UI, but I am guessing a change of data set cursor position doesn't count as a change, which makes sense. You don't want the UI changing every time you are calculation something on the data set in the background. So, the obvious answer is to change the UI (ListView) programmatically instead.

Comment: Since I posted the question, the answer came to me. The simple way to do it, is to change the `ListView1.Itemindex` programmatically (and to remember to call the `Listview1.OnChange` handler because the documentation says you have to do it yourself in this situation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181326/discussion-between-dsm-and-nolaspeaker).

Comment: OK I'll delete my comments too.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer to this question is to perform a

```
if ClientModule.CDSData.Locate('PKID', VarArrayOf([PKIDValue]), []) then
```

It seems that while moving the record pointer using `CDSData.Next` doesn't sync back to the Live(Bound) `Listview`, using a `locate` does.